# Install MariaDB on Bionic

Tags: apt, software-installation, mariadb

For the life of me, I can not figure out why I am unable to install mariadb-server 10.2 on my new install of Ubuntu Mate 18.04. I've done this twice on two computers running 16.04 without incident. I'm following the instructions [here](https://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/repositories/#mirror=23Media&distro=Ubuntu&distro_release=xenial--ubuntu_xenial&version=10.2) but to no avail.

After importing the keys and setting the repository, I attempt to install with `sudo apt install mariadb-server` and am prompted that `mariadb-server-10.1` will be installed.

I have attempted with 2 different mirrors as well as attempted to install with the Artful and Xenial dists on those mirrors (since there is no current dist for bionic)

Comment: The link you provided looks like it hasn’t been supported on 18.04 yet…

Comment: This is true; however, I have some other programs which are being installed via repositories which default to artful and are working just fine.

Comment: Out of desperation I tried `sudo apt-get install mariadb-server-10.2` It worked and I have absolutely no idea why :-( Sorry to bog up the board

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow the instructions on the [MariaDB site](https://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/repositories/#mirror=hs-esslingen&distro=Ubuntu&distro_release=xenial--ubuntu_xenial&version=10.2). I ended up finding the solution using "xenial", but I suppose it would work with "artful" as well.

The problem is that when you run `sudo apt install mariadb-server` it will pull down the version from "bionic", which is currently 10.1. You should run `sudo apt install mariadb-server-10.2` instead.

After installing 10.1, running `sudo apt install mariadb-server-10.2` will pull in the version from your custom repository and uninstall all the mariadb-server 10.1 files which are not dependencies.

Answer (score -1):

Personally it didnt worked for me with

> sudo apt install mariadb-server-10.1

so what I did is :

```
sudo apt install mariadb-server-core-10.1
```